# How do I scale CGPoint based on CGSize changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgpoint

I have CGRect with a default (square) size.  The size is adjustable based on the view controllers needs, but always maintains a square proportion.

If I want to plot a point within the rect, but the scale of the rect is variable up and down in size, how would I calculate the new point position based on the change in rect size?

```
// in a UIView object, values always positive
- (CGPoint)convertPointToViewSizeScale:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGSize defaultSize = kViewSizeDefault;
    CGSize currentSize = self.frame.size;
    // ...
    return point;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the bounds.size.width and bounds.size.height to make adjustments for the new size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
point.x *= currentSize.width / defaultSize.width;
point.y *= currentSize.height / defaultSize.height;
```